# After Overclocking GPU, how to bring it back

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, overclocking, msi-afterburner

I used MSI Afterburner and did a test and scan for Overclocking GPU.

My GPU is Gigabyte NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti Windforce OC 11GB.

Just wondering, how it bring it back to normal clocking after Overclocking?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use the same tool?

Comment: hi @GabrielaGarcia I do not know, I want to make sure I can bring it back then I will do the OC